# How can I make this System V init script start at boot?

Tags: raspberry-pi, init-script, raspbian, init.d, sysvinit

I've installed [udisks-glue](https://github.com/fernandotcl/udisks-glue) on my Raspbian Raspberry Pi, along with a System V init [script](https://gist.github.com/abythell/5399914) at `/etc/init.d/udisks-glue` (as per instructions [here](http://angryelectron.com/udisks-glue-initscript/)). I make it executable and run the following, which returns no errors.

```
sudo update-rc.d udisks-glue defaults
```

I can start the script fine, and it works as expected.

```
$ sudo service udisks-glue start
[ ok ] Starting Automounter: udisks-glue.
$ sudo service udisks-glue status
[ ok ] udisks-glue is running.
```

However, when I reboot, it's not running. This used to work fine, but I reinstalled a minimal system, and it no longer works. It's possible that I'm missing some packages.

```
$ sudo service udisks-glue status
[FAIL] udisks-glue is not running ... failed!
```

### Troubleshooting

I've tried to log output and errors by changing a line in the `start)` block to

```
start-stop-daemon --start --exec $DAEMON -- -p $PIDFILE &>> /tmp/udisks-glue.log
```

This file is empty on reboot. However, it does exist, suggesting that the script is at least partially executed.

Finally, I've tried to confirm proper installation. Amongst other things, `locate udisks-glue` returns

```
/etc/rc0.d/K01udisks-glue
/etc/rc1.d/K01udisks-glue
/etc/rc2.d/S01udisks-glue
/etc/rc3.d/S01udisks-glue
/etc/rc4.d/S01udisks-glue
/etc/rc5.d/S01udisks-glue
/etc/rc6.d/K01udisks-glue
```

### EDIT — Further troubleshooting

I thought I might test if the script was acting too early, so I tested two possible solutions. Both failed. Firstly, I tried making the script run at a lower priority.

```
mv /etc/rc2.d/S{01,90}udisks-glue
```

Secondly, I reverted this then inserted `sleep 90` into the `start)` block, just before the `start-stop-daemon` invocation.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your Rasp Pi device is running in a runlevel other than 2, 3, 4, or 5, given your `/etc/rc*.d` directories contain links to your `udisks-glue` script. The way you can tell this is the links that start with a K will kill your script/service when in one of those runlevels while an S will start it.

I'd double check your runlevel and then adjust the link in the corresponding runlevel's directory.

#### What's my runlevel

You can typically run this command to find this out.

```
$ runlevel
N 5
```

So my system is in runlevel 5.

Comment: `runlevel` returns `N 2`. I can see `/etc/rc2.d/S01udisks-glue` exists, so does that mean that it should have been running? (Also, from the previously-linked [script](https://gist.github.com/abythell/5399914), `# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5`)

Comment: @Sparhawk - that looks correct, I had a typo in the A, 2 should be starting the script.

Comment: No worries, I suspected this, and assumed it was a typo. :) I guess this is a dead end, though. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @Sparhawk - does the log file exist when you go looking for it? That would imply that your script ran and nothing was put into it. If it doesn't exist then the script didn't even run.

Comment: Yes, it exists, but is empty.

Comment: @Sparhawk - so that would imply your script ran. I'd change out the script so that it just does an `echo "hi"` to the log file. I suspect your use of `&>>` might be at issue here. You could try changing that to `<cmd> >/tmp/udisks-glue.log 2>&1`.

Comment: I tried the changes, and "hi" does echo to a file. The latter change makes no difference (the script specifies `#!/bin/bash`, so it should be okay, although it's definitely worth a shot).

Comment: @Sparhawk - if the output is showing up with the echo then there's an issue with the command not producing output.

Comment: Yes, I think perhaps it doesn't produce output? When I get it to run properly when I manually invoke with `sudo service udisks-glue start` there is no output. Nor when I invoke with `udisks-glue` FWIW.

Comment: @Sparhawk - OK, so the service/process is simply not running afterwards?

Comment: Yes, it runs fine if I trigger it manually with `sudo service udisks-glue start`, but not on reboot.

Comment: @Sparhawk - what does udisks-glue look like?

Comment: Do you mean what does it do? I use it to automatically mount connected USD drives. (More info [here](https://github.com/fernandotcl/udisks-glue).) But I can easily test if the daemon is running with `pgrep udisks-glue`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, then I went to

```
cd /etc/init.d/
```

and gave the udisks-glue to root

```
 sudo chown root: udisks-glue
```

an tried it with

```
sudo reboot
```

And it worked like a charme!

Comment: As per the instructions linked in the question, I ran `sudo cp udisks-glue /etc/init.d/.`, which already makes this script owned by root. (The -1 wasn't me.)

Comment: I also had some issues with copying the script. I got it then with git and it worked. I do not remember what issue. May be one more try... Otherwise I have no ideas.

Comment: I've tried it several times, with both copy-paste and git. As per the question, (I think) I had it working before I created the minimal install, so perhaps it's missing packages. Thanks anyway.